# RecursiveAction cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, openjdk-17

When I add jdk17.0.2 to my build path, in STS(eclipse), replacing 15, RecursiveAction cannot be resolved to a type. What gives? I know java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction was not removed from the jdk. Reverting back to 15 solves it.

Comment: I think something may be messed up with Project Facets (Project ->Properties->Project Facets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ceased to be a problem, which suggests problems with the IDE(STS).